# Vectorization/optimising for loop with numpy in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Im writing a script to handle some data from a sensor represented in the signal_gen function. As you can see in the testing function it is quite loop sentered. Since this function is called many times it makes it a bit slow and it would be lovely with a push in the right direction for optimising it.

I have read that it is possible to exchange the for loop with a vectorizatid array, but I can't get my head around how the i_avg[i] line should be written, since we have single element y[i] multiplied with the whole array x inside a np.cos, and all this is again just one irritation of i_avg.

```
def testing(signal):
    y = np.arange(0.0108, 0.0135, 0.001) # this one changes over time, set 
    #to constant for easier reading
    x = np.arange(0, (len(signal)))
    I_avg = np.zeros(len(y))
    Q_avg = np.zeros_like(I_avg)
    for i in range(0, len(y)):
        I_avg[i] = np.array(signal * (np.cos(2 * np.pi * y[i] * x))).sum()
        Q_avg[i] = np.array(signal * (np.sin(2 * np.pi * y[i] * x))).sum()
    D = np.power(I_avg, 2) + np.power(Q_avg, 2)
    max_index = np.argmax(D)
    phaseOut = np.arctan2(Q_avg[max_index], I_avg[max_index])

#just a test signal
def signal_gen():
    signal = np.random.random(size=251)
    return signal
```

Comment: max_index is another typo. did you test this code?

Comment: I did, but I guess I was sloppy when i changed a couple of variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One vectorized approach using `matrix-multiplication` with [`numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to replace the nested loop to give us `I_avg, Q_avg` and also incorporating [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and thus achieve a more efficient solution would be like so -

```
mult = 2*np.pi*y[:,None]*x
I_avg, Q_avg = np.cos(mult).dot(signal), np.sin(mult).dot(signal)
```

Please note that for the given sample, we are competing against a loopy version that only has to iterate for `3` iterations (`y` being of length `3`). As such, we won't be seeing a huge speedup here.

Runtime test -

```
In [9]: #just a test signal
   ...: signal = np.random.random(size=251)
   ...: y = np.arange(0.0108, 0.0135, 0.001)
   ...: x = np.arange(0, (len(signal)))
   ...: 

# Original approach
In [10]: %%timeit I_avg = np.zeros(len(y))
    ...: Q_avg = np.zeros_like(I_avg)
    ...: for i in range(0, len(y)):
    ...:     I_avg[i] = np.array(signal * (np.cos(2 * np.pi * y[i] * x))).sum()
    ...:     Q_avg[i] = np.array(signal * (np.sin(2 * np.pi * y[i] * x))).sum()
    ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 68 µs per loop

# Proposed approach
In [11]: %%timeit mult = 2*np.pi*y[:,None]*x
    ...: I_avg, Q_avg = np.cos(mult).dot(signal), np.sin(mult).dot(signal)
    ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: we could also use `np.newaxis` instead of hard-coding `None` there. Just a suggestion, although both are essentially the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for broadcasting:

```
yx = 2*np.pi*np.einsum("i,j->ij", y, x)
I_avg = np.sin(yx) @ signal    
Q_avg = np.cos(yx) @ signal
```